# Problems aroung the fonts

Tags: fonts

I have a problem and I have no idea how to solve it. The file will be compiled **but the fonts are not the right**.

I tried to adopt the fonts from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVCJ5.png)
here are my warning

[image]

Infos about the texlive:

```
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Karl Berry & Olaf Weber.
License LGPLv2.1+: GNU Lesser GPL version 2.1
```

I downloaded the fonts from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVCJ5.png), it has two folders:  pfb (*.pfm, *pfb, *.inf, *.afm) and ttf (*.ttf)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVCJ5.png) - https://download.hrz.tu-darmstadt.de/protected/DezIF/Corporate_Design/Schriften/tu-darmstadt-schriften_jan08.zip

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal compilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Your thesis template file appears to be trying to use some fonts you don’t have installed. We can’t really help you, though, unless you give us a minimal example that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Davislor I did all for the fornt installation, I don't know further ...

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the smallest document you can that reproduces this problem, but you might also ask whoever gave you the template which fonts it needs. These fonts do not appear to be on CTAN.

Comment: Which fonts did you install? What did you do exactly?

Comment: @RalfStubner the fonts are from this site https://www.intern.tu-darmstadt.de/arbeitsmittel/corporate_design_vorlagen/index.de.jsp

Comment: @RalfStubner I tried to replicate this manual https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12771, however I couldn't do the 3rd step with the map

Comment: @malocho What TeX system are you using?

Comment: These fonts are available only within TU Darmstadt. What is the content of that archive?The error message indicates that you  are missing the `fd` files. The quoted manual assumes that fd and tfm files are available from CTAN. I am not sure this is the case here.

Comment: @RalfStubner I can access to them being out of the TU Darmstadt network. Content is pfb (*.pfm, *pfb, *.inf, *.afm) and ttf (*.ttf) folders.

Comment: @egreg kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Karl Berry & Olaf Weber.
License LGPLv2.1+: GNU Lesser GPL version 2.1